# Pass variable to _preprocess_node function for use in node template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I've been racking my brains over this one but I'll do my best to describe the problem as best as possible. I have a custom function written within template.php, with a bunch of conditionals. When a condition is true, I would like to assign a value to a variable, and then pass that variable intro a node preprocess function that allows that variables to be rendered on a node template.

**The function containing the condition:**

```
function _mytheme_date_repeat_string($vars) {

    $exdate_pos = strpos($rrule['WKST'], 'EXDATE:');
    if($exdate_pos > 0) {

        $vars['testvar'] = 'abc123';
    }
 }
```

**The preprocess function that I would like to render the variable in for node template use:**

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {

  $vars['new_variable'] = $testvar;

}
```

**Intended usage in node.tpl.php:**

```
<?php print $new_variable; ?>
```

I'm not great with PHP, but I know enough about programming to know that variable scope might be an issue here. What would be the best way to implement this? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: you can use $GLOBALS array to save it http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 0):

If it is not called, your `_mytheme_date_repeat_string()` function will never be executed. Preprocess functions (ie. any function starting `mytheme_preprocess_`, are called automatically by Drupal's theme system.

What you need is either move the code of `_mytheme_date_repeat_string()` in `mytheme_preprocess_node()` or refactor it and call it.

```
function _mytheme_date_repeat_string($rrule) {
    $exdate_pos = strpos($rrule['WKST'], 'EXDATE:');
    if($exdate_pos > 0) {
      return 'abc123';
    }
    else {
      return NULL;
    }
 }

/**
 * Prepares variables for node templates.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

  // Get $rrule from somewhere
  $rrule = ... ;

  $testvar = _mytheme_date_repeat_string($rrule);
  if ($testvar) {
    $variables['new_variable'] = $testvar;
  }
}
```

You code does not show where the `$rrule` calue comes from. I assume you would get it for `$variables['node']`.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. This is a watered down version of my code that's incomplete. In my actual code the function is being returned and executed. I more or less wanted to know how I could save a value into a variable, _within_ that function, and call that variable with that value elsewhere in the preprocess_node function for template usage.

Comment: Update your question with a code that reflect what is realy happening and I could update my answer. If you pass around `$vars` and receive it by reference (ie. `&$vars`) in all you functions, then you can use it a a big bin to pass data around. Be aware that this leads to hard to read code since you don't known, from functions' signatures, what they consume and return.